# How to pass a set of values present in the form of a list into a neural network and predict its output

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a list  `[0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]` and want to pass this to a neural network to predict its output ..How to do that

I tried converting it into an array, but that didnt work saying it is not of suitable dimensions

```
classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 64, init = 'uniform', activation= 'relu', input_dim = 15))

#adding second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 64, init = 'uniform', activation= 'relu'))

#adding last layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 28, init = 'uniform', activation= 'softmax'))

#compiling ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

#fitting ann to training set
classifier.fit(xtrain, ytrain, batch_size =10, nb_epoch = 10)


testarray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
classifier.predict(testarray)
```

I'm expecting it to predict a number, but it is showing the error message

> Error when checking input: expected dense_13_input to have shape (15,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: Try `testarray = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]` (note the double brackets). Usually models expect "Lists of rows", so you want an input array with one row of dimension 15.

Comment: This appears to be Keras (you failed to include any overt indication).  If so, take a closer look at the documentation for the dimensions: these are *dimensions*, not *shape*.  You told it to expect a 15-dimensional input.  Try @johnpaton's solution and adjust your layer descriptions to match.

Comment: thanks @johnpaton.The solution you gave worked